# Vertically center div in parent bigger than screen-height

Tags: css

I'm trying to vertically center a div on the viewport tho the parent div has a height bigger than the screen. I got it working like this:

```
<div class="absolute z-20 left-0 top-0 flex flex-col justify-start items-center" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75); height: 100%; width: 99vw;">
  <div class="z-50 h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full">
    FIXED CENTERED ELEMENT HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using two flex-columns with their contents centered. It's working but I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `margin: top;` on your div

```css
div {
  margin-top: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute z-20 left-0 top-0 flex flex-col justify-start items-center" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75); height: 100%; width: 99vw;">
  <div class="z-50 h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full">
    FIXED CENTERED ELEMENT HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question wasn't about to center it horizontally, but vertically on the viewport when the parent has a bigger height than the actual screen height.

Comment: @TKsomewhat see edits